# Prestashop Validator Issue for Library files

Tags: php, validation, static-libraries, prestashop, dompdf

I have developed a new module for prestashop and it is using dompdf library for generating pdf.

When I validate the module then I get some compatibility issues that are pointing to some errors that say:

> 'Class 'PDFLib' does not exists'
>
> 'Function 'pg_query()' does not exists'
>
> 'Function 'pg_escape_string()' does not exists'

The above errors are coming in various files withing the dompdf library and I do not find a way to fix them.

Comment: I have no knowledge of Prestashop. Does the validation occur outside of script processing? The PDFLib class is an optional PHP extension that has to be enabled in the dompdf configuration.

Comment: Same goes for the "pg_" functions. They're in a class that isn't fully implemented. That code should *probably* be moved into a feature branch of the project until it's finalized.

Comment: When a module in prestashop is complete then it has to be validated on validator.prestashop.com before uploading on the addon store. These errors are coming in my module(using DOMPDF library) while I am validating my module on the validator.

Comment: Your second comment is not at all clear to me.. Can you please explain it again? So that I can understand.

Comment: My second comment is in regard to our code development process and source code management (SCM) strategy. Those functions shouldn't be in released code since they aren't fully implemented.

Comment: I'd have to double check, but you can probably remove the class file that calls the pg_* functions. You can probably also remove the relevant PDFLib class file, but you might need to make some changes elsewhere in the code to validate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about validation errors in library files while uploading a module on PrestaShop addons store for approval.

Just upload your module for approval process, I am pretty much sure that they will ignore all dompdf validation errors and will approve your module.